# In PHP - benefit of returning content by 'ob_get_clean()' as compared to 'return'?

Tags: php

What's the benefit of returning content by 'ob_get_clean()' as compared to simple 'return'?  Although 'doSomething()' will work in a different way either 'return or echo'. What's the benefit of using one approach over the other.

For e.g

```
ob_start();
$this->doSomething();
ob_get_clean();
```

---  as compared to ---

```
return $this->doSomething();
```

Comment: What is the context of these 2 examples?  It's like comparing apples and cars.

Comment: What I wanted to know was the benefit of using one approach over the other. I know function 'doSomething()' need to work differently either 'return or echo', but I want to know is which approach is better?

Comment: @BostonGuy: Neither is "better" as they are not the same.  There is no answer to your question.  Use whichever fits better in your program and/or whichever makes more sense in your program's context.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Can't agree with you totally. At least I can say that both can be used to return a value from a function or return a string in the output buffer(filled by a function).

Comment: @BostonGuy: Well, in your 1st example, you're not saving the result of `ob_get_clean`, you're just throwing it away.  Which is "better" all depends on what `$this->doSomething();` does, so... what does it do?  Does it `echo` something or does it `return` something?  How is it used?  Is it called elsewhere?  There's no "better" or "worse", it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 10):

They're two completely different things.

`return` *returns* a value from a function.

`ob_get_clean` returns a *string* of whatever has entered the output buffer since your `ob_start()` call and then deletes the contents from the buffer(in this particular example you never set the output of this function to anything, so your code should do nothing).

Using `return`:

```
function foo() {
    return 'abc';
}

echo foo();
```

Using `ob_get_clean` (note that we `echo` instead of `return` inside the function):

```
function foo() {
    echo 'abc';
}

ob_start();
foo();
echo ob_get_clean();
```

**Do not use output buffers unless you need to.**

Comment: Completely unclear why you got +4 for this. Maybe kids aren't sleeping already? Please answer the question (it can't be answered, as it is unclear so why are you are *just* talking?)

Comment: @hek2mgl Personally I don't believe it to be an unclear question, but if you do, you're more than welcome to close-vote it as unclear. :-)

Comment: no no, if everyone thinks the question is clear then it's ok for me. I think without having more context as provided by the question these topics are just un-comparable.

Answer (score 6):

As an example, Wordpress has two sets of functions for most everything related to producing output for a WP-based site. There'll be `foo()` which generates some content, and outputs it. And then a `getfoo()` version that generates the same content, but RETURNS it instead of outputting.

In practical terms, it'd be bad practice to completely duplicate all of the code in the functions and only change one line:

```
function foo() {
   ...do lots of stuff
   echo $generated_content;
}
function getfoo() {
   ...do exactly the same stuff
   return $generated_content;  // the only line that'd be different
}
```

Instead of the massive code duplication, you could simply have

```
function getfoo() {
   ... do lots of stuff
  return $generated_content;
}

function foo() {
    echo getfoo();  // call getfoo() and output it automatically
}
```

Or go the other way:

```
function foo() {
   ... do lots of stuff
   echo $generated_content;
}
function getfoo() {
   ob_start();
   foo();
   return ob_end_clean();
}
```

Both versions would accomplish the same thing, but do it in different ones. One simply gets the return value of its "cousin" function, and outputs it. The other works in the other direction and captures the output of the cousin function, and returns the captured data.

Comment: Nice explanation, but the performance impact of the output buffer is definitely non-neglegible, and so, a recommendation to use the “return” way is a definitive *must* here.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `return "string"` is much faster, but only possible if the *called* function returns things as string. So, it depends on what `$this->doSomething()` does.

If `doSomething` uses functions like `echo`, `print_r`, `?> … <?php`, `fpassthrough`, etc. you need to use the output buffer, in order to be able to capture it. If it doesn’t, and returns the string, just return that.

---

Example about output buffering:

```
function yours_echoing() {
    echo "Hello, World!\n";
}

function mine() {
    ob_start();
    yours_echoing();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Versus:

```
function yours_returning() {
    return "Hello, World!\n";
}

function mine() {
    return yours_returning();
}
```

Which one to choose depends purely on what the functions I call (“yours”) do.

Output buffering being faster is wholly different: on a whole-program scope, and *without* doing the `ob_get_clean()` dance, it can improve page transmission times (from the webserver to the webbrowser) by transmitting everything at once (and possibly compressed) instead of in chunks. But that's a **different** output buffering than the technique employed here, which is capturing one other function’s output.

Comment: is much faster than ... ?

Comment: is much faster than… using an output buffer. Sorry, thought this was clear from the context.

Comment: output buffering can speed up things a lot. depends on how you are using it. Sorry the answer is meaningless (as the question)

Comment: No, abusing output buffering when returning a string could be used instead is much slower. I will amend my answer with an example proving why, even if this has not much to do with the original question any more.

Comment: The only thing I am interested to know is which approach is better?

Comment: “return” is better **iff** you can do it. If the called function echos, you cannot do it, in which case you *have* to use the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 examples are *completely* different.  They have absolutely no similarities.

Which is "better"?  It all depends on what `$this->doSomething();` does.  Does it actually have a return value?  Does it `echo` to the screen?

---

```
return $this->doSomething();
```

This runs `doSomething()` and then returns whatever it returns.  That's it.

On the other hand, the other example:

```
ob_start();
$this->doSomething();
ob_get_clean();
```

What this does is captures anything that `doSomething()` prints to the screen (using `echo` or similar) in an output buffer.  It then gets the buffer as a string and immediately discards it.

`ob_get_clean` returns a string, so it needs to be saved into a variable to be useful.

Comment: `These 2 examples are completely different.` Thanks that someone is saying this! :) +1